# SSL and truststore result in jsseUtil.trustedCertNotValid warnings

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

I have set up a Spring Boot application to utilize HTTPS with a certificate (not self-signed) in a PKCS12 keystore.

I created the keystore like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key -in cert -certfile interm -out tls-keystore.p12 -name tomcat
```

The configuration properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/app/tls-keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

I am using a trust store (a different file) which is a copy of the default JVM keystore with two extra certs inserted (so we can talk to a local service that uses self-signed certs).

The SSL works, but there are a number of warnings in the log:

`2020-03-12 13:23:14.842  WARN 11572 --- [           main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase   : jsseUtil.trustedCertNotValid`

There are 30 of these. It doesn't seem like they can correspond to certificates in the keystore I've created, because it only has one entry.

Looking at the code it appears that the warning was intended to be rendered as a more informative message, but failed: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLUtilBase.java?revision=1854079&view=markup&pathrev=1854079#l296

If either SSL or the alternate trust store are turned off, the warnings don't appear.

I did enable debugging: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:keymanager:trustmanager -Djava.security.debug=jca,certpath,provider

which resulted in quite a bit of extra information logged, but none adjacent to the warnings in question.

What is causing these warnings and what should I do about them?

Comment: Do you also have `server.ssl.trust-store` configured? It sounds like the errors are coming from that.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code that generates the message and track it down from there. If it is using the usual Java built-in cert verification algo, you can track down what is going by setting environment variable [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) to something like this `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:keymanager:trustmanager -Djava.security.debug=jca,certpath,provider`

Comment: One more point, I have seen otherwise valid certificates failing validation when neither OSCP nor CRL was available as a method of validation. My case was with Jetty though.

Comment: It is OCSP, not OSCP.

Comment: It looks like their valid time period has expired, at least from the exceptions the code catches. Check the certificates using some other tool, like `keytool -list`.